# Why contract's function that is deploy inside Solidity browser does not deployed inside geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, gas, contract-deployment, remix

I have my private Ethereum Network.

**Inside Solidity Browser:**

1. From Web3 Provider I have connected to my local ethereum node.
2. I have pressed `create` button and successfully deployed my contract.
3. Now I could call any function inside my contract and all deployed without having any problem.

### [image]

As an example: I have deployed `insertfront(string val)` transaction inside Solidity Browser (To get mined takes around a minute). Gas costs is 203893.

[image]

**Inside Geth:**

1. Connect into private ethereum network.
2. Obtain address and abi (located inside the interface box) from the Solidity Browser that will point the deployed contract.

   ### [image]
3. `var mycontract = eth.contract(abi).at(address)`

`mycontract
{
...
  insertfront: function(),
  allEvents: function(),
  construct: function(),
  delete_: function(),
  delete_items: function(),
  deleteback: function(),
  deletefront: function(),
  get: function(),
  get_: function(),
  get_map: function(),
...
}`

4. `mycontract.deletefront( {from: eth.accounts[0]} )` //This works inside geth and function does what it has to do. Transaction mines and deploys. deletefront() function's gas usage is 41920.
5. But when I call `insertfront(string val)` function inside geth (please not that transaction has costed 203893 gas inside Solidity Browser), it never deploys or mines in my blockchain (I have waited hours but no help).

   `> mycontract.insertfront("some_string", {from: eth.accounts[0]} )
   "0x7048278dcdb02c02894082af541c73ad6a8e0e37cf1ab90ac914c58cc2d2f983"`

//But it has no affect and did not done the what function has to do.

[Q] Why function that is deploy inside Solidity browser does not deployed inside geth? Could it be because usage of high gas amount for a function?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know right off, but I'd suspect it's indeed a gas problem. geth, by default, provides only 90k gas, which wouldn't be enough. You can set the gas inside the transaction like this: `{from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 300000}`. Note that you'll want to set the gas, not the *gasPrice*. Don't worry about getting it exact, since any unused gas is refunded.

Here's an additional tip to help debug: use `web3.getTransaction()` and `web3.getTransactionReceipt()`. The hex string geth is giving you after a transaction (i.e. `"0x7048278dcdb02c02894082af541c73ad6a8e0e37cf1ab90ac914c58cc2d2f983"`) is the hash of that transaction. By using `getTransactionReceipt(hash)`, you'll see what happened. If `getTransactionReceipt()` says the transaction used as much gas as `getTransaction()` said it had in the first place, the transaction most likely went out of gas.